# How to arrange scala parallel collections in insertion order?

Tags: scala, vector, scala-collections

Consider the below example:

```
object Test {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val vec = Vector(1,2,3,4,5,6)
  val x = vec.map(myFunc(_))
  x.foreach{println}

  val par = vec.par
  val parx = par.map(myFunc(_))
  parx.foreach{println}
}

def myFunc(a:Int) : Int  = {
 return a*a
 }
}
```

when I print `x`, it follows insertion order, while `parx` follows random order. How to preserve the insertion order here? I'm using Vector in this example, but it happens in other collections such as `List` too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`parx` is a parallel collection so all operations on it are done in parallel, including `foreach`. So all the `println` operations are executed in parallel, and you cannot control the order in which they complete.

If you want to go back to a sequential collection, call `.seq` on the collection.

```
parx.seq.foreach(println)
```